# javac unexpectedly expanding jars found in my classpath

Tags: java, classpath, javac

I'm running into some curious behavior that I haven't seen before with javac and am wondering what I may be doing differently this time to cause it.

I'm compiling a relatively simple application with javac.  The application depends on a handful of libraries that I refer to in the class path argument.

The after successfully compiling (albeit with some warnings that I believe are from the libs) I end up with a large amount of .class files that seem to have been extracted from the jar files in my library folder.

I've never seen javac expand my libraries like this and would like to keep it from doing this.  My only hypothesis is that wildcarding in the classpath may behave differently than explicitly referring to each jar separately.

Below is the folder structure:

```
/loadtest
/loadtest/lib
/loadtest/lib/selenium
  <some jars here>
/loadtest/lib/selenium/libs
  <some jars here>
/loadtest/src
/loadtest/src/com/example/test
  <my java files here>
```

Here is the javac command I'm issuing from /loadtest/src

```
javac -classpath .;../lib/*;../lib/selenium/*;../lib/selenium/libs/* com/example/test/AdobeSSOLoadTester.java
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.  It's obviously not a show stopper, but it is turning my simple build into an unnecessarily complicated mess.  Thanks!

Comment: You **shouldn't** get warnings about classes in `.jar` files. **If** you get warnings from the library classes, that means that you are **compiling** the library classes. Chances are that you have the library source files relative to your working directory and `javac` compiles them, because it sees that they are referenced from the file you specified on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for that tip too.  It didn't really make sense to me that I'd be getting errors from my jar's but it didn't click that it must be trying to compile additional source other than my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think is a problem with `javac` at all, but rather with the build classpath that you have. I suspect that you have some JARs with sources in your classpath, most notably `selenium-java-x.y.z-srcs.jar` in your `/loadtest/lib/selenium` directory.

Since you haven't specified a `-sourcepath` argument in your `javac` invocation, the Oracle/Sun compiler will also search your user classpath for source files, as noted in the [`javac` technote](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html):

> ### Standard Options
>
> ...
>
> **-cp path or -classpath path**
>
> Specify where to find user class files,
>   and (optionally) annotation processors and source files. This
>   classpath overrides the user class path in the CLASSPATH environment
>   variable. If neither CLASSPATH, -cp nor -classpath is specified, the
>   user class path consists of the current directory. See Setting the
>   Class Path for more details.
>
> **If the -sourcepath option is not specified, the user class path is
>   also searched for source files.**
>
> ...
>
> **-sourcepath sourcepath**
>
> Specify the source code path to search for
>   class or interface definitions. As with the user class path, source
>   path entries are separated by semicolons (;) and can be **directories,
>   JAR archives, or ZIP archives**. If packages are used, the local path
>   name within the directory or archive must reflect the package name.
>   Note:   Classes found through the classpath may be subject to
>   automatic recompilation if their sources are also found. See Searching
>   For Types.

Comment: Yeah i didn't figure javac was broken.  I just couldn't figure out what the heck I'm doing.  I bet you're right on the srcs jar.  I'm going to take that out and try again, I had just copied my libs over from my development area where I had the srcs dir for documentation.

Comment: The selenium-src jar was my guess. It could have been any other file.

Comment: Yup, dropping the src jar fixed it.  Thanks for the quick response and the clarification on how classpath can perform double duty as sourcepath if it's not provided.